# Get global vars everywhere from Extjs MVC Application

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm learning ExtJs framework 4.2.2 MVC and i want to get a global var declared in Application.js:

```
Ext.define('XApp.Application', {
    name: 'XApp',

    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:31109/',

    requires: [
        'XApp.util.Util',
        'XApp.util.SessionMonitor'
    ],

    views: [       
    ],

    controllers: [
       'Login',
       'Main',
       'Mail'
    ]
});
```

I want to get **serverUrl** from everywhere, because in future i want to change this url of server back-end.
In "Application" extended class i found this var with 
XApp.app.serverUrl
But from my store, this syntax does not work:

```
Ext.define('XApp.store.Xusers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [ 'XApp.model.Xuser'],
    model: 'XApp.model.Xuser',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: XApp.app.serverUrl + 'Login/Loadusers',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
        }
    },
});
```

Firebug tellme:
*TypeError: XApp.app is undefined*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is requiring things, that require things, that end up requiring your XUsers store. At this time, Ext's class manager is still build classes and such and has not yet launched your application; that explains your undefined error.

To solve it, you can use it in a class method, that will necessarily be called after the app has launched, for example in the constructor of your store:

```
Ext.define('XApp.store.Xusers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [ 'XApp.model.Xuser'],
    model: 'XApp.model.Xuser',

    constructor: function() {
        this.proxy = {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: XApp.app.serverUrl + 'Login/Loadusers',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
            }
        };
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

That said, with your use case, I think I'd rather define a customized proxy with the URL prefix like such:

```
Ext.define('XApp.data.proxy.DefaultJsonP', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',

    alias: 'proxy.xjsonp',

    urlPrefix: 'http://localhost:31109/',

    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    },

    constructor: function() {
        // we want the config to have been applied beforehand this time
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.url = this.urlPrefix + this.url;
    }
});
```